# How to get combine Value from xml by PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell

i have an data.xml with following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<animetitles>
    <anime aid="1">
        <title type="short" xml:lang="en">CotS</title>
        <title xml:lang="fr" type="official">Crest of the Stars</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="en">Crest of the Stars</title>
        <title xml:lang="pl" type="official">Crest of the Stars</title>
        <title type="syn" xml:lang="cs">Hvězdný erb</title>
        <title type="main" xml:lang="x-jat">Seikai no Monshou</title>
        <title xml:lang="x-jat" type="short">SnM</title>
        <title type="syn" xml:lang="ko">성계의 문장</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="ja">星界の紋章</title>
        <title xml:lang="zh-Hans" type="syn">星界之纹章</title>
    </anime>
    <anime aid="2">
        <title type="official" xml:lang="ja">3×3 EYES</title>
        <title type="short" xml:lang="x-jat">3x3</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="de">3x3 Augen (OVA 1)</title>
        <title type="main" xml:lang="x-jat">3x3 Eyes</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="en">3x3 Eyes</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="fr">3x3 Eyes</title>
        <title xml:lang="en" type="syn">3x3 Eyes - Immortals</title>
        <title xml:lang="it" type="official">3x3 Occhi</title>
        <title xml:lang="cs" type="official">3x3 Oči</title>
        <title xml:lang="sv" type="official">3x3 Ögon</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="es">3x3 Ojos [1-4]</title>
        <title type="official" xml:lang="ca">3x3 Ulls</title>
        <title xml:lang="ru" type="syn">3x3 глаза</title>
        <title type="syn" xml:lang="x-jat">Sazan Eyes</title>
        <title type="syn" xml:lang="x-jat">Southern Eyes</title>
        <title type="syn" xml:lang="ja">サザンアイズ</title>
        <title xml:lang="zh-x-nan" type="syn">三隻眼</title>
    </anime>
</animetitles>
```

i can manage to get the aid with powershell with the following

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path data.xml
$XmlDocument.animetitles.anime.aid
```

and i can get select the titel with the require id with the following

for example aid = 1 and get the titel with tag main

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path C:\testxml\data.xml
$XmlDocument.animetitles.anime | Where-Object {$_.aid -eq 1} | Select-Object -property title | ForEach-Object title | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'main'}
```

i would like to combine both information but i dont have an idea how, i was wonder if someone can point me to the right direction? What i would like to archive is for example to have extract the information with 2 column, 1 for aid and the title info

aid and title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can use a combination of `Where` and `Select-Object` with calculated properties to get the information you want.

**Display Both Properties with No Conditions**

```
$XmlDocument.animetitles.anime | Select-Object aid,@{n='title';e={$_.Title.'#text'}}
```

**Display Both Properties with Conditions**

```
$XmlDocument.animetitles.anime |
    Where {$_.aid -eq 1} |
        Select-Object aid,@{n='title';e={$_.Title.where{$_.Type -eq 'main'}.'#text'}}
```